# Ijen crater and batu secret zoo from Surabaya

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, indonesia, volcanoes, zoos

I am going to Surabaya from where we plan to take a Mt. Bromo tour.

I was wondering if anyone has been to Ijen Crater and Batu secret zoo. Is it worth the travelling distance? Bearing in mind that I will go to Mt. Bromo, how similar is it to go to Ijen Crater. And we are heading to Komodo and Tanjung Puting so not sure how great the zoo will be. Anyone who can give me some insight into these 2 places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a lack of answer here I can tell you what I figured out. Apparently it is better to stay in Malang rather than Surabaya.

From there I saw that there is a Bromo & Ijen tour (together). From Malang, Batu Secret Zoo is also much closer.

Comment: I've been to Bromo but I've only seen pictures of Ijen, it does seem very different.

Answer (score 3):

I've been to Mount Bromo and Ijen crater many times.
If you want to get a good view and landscape then better you go to Mount Bromo, take the picture on Penanjakan viewpoint, you'll get the picture:
[image: Mount Bromo from Penanjakan viewpoint]

But if you want to see the big crater with toxic water and sulfur (and blue fire at night) with the chance of getting closer to the crater, then better to choose Ijen.
Here's Ijen crater, [image: Ijen crater]

Have a good trip then.